# Returning response from Mongoose promise

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

Followup from this question > [Stopping response if document isn't found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553558/stopping-response-if-document-isnt-found) since it was recommended I use Promise.

So basic premise, I want node to return "Can't find ID" message if we can't find the id in our database.

```
v1.post("/", function(req, res) {

    // If the project_id isn't provided, return with an error.
    if ( !("project_id" in req.body) ) {
        return res.send("You need to provide Project ID");
    }

    // Check if the Project ID is in the file.
    helper.documentExists( ProjectsData, {project_id: req.body.project_id} )
        .then(function(c) {
            if ( c == 0 ) {
                return res.send("The provided Project Id does not exist in our database.");
            } else {
                var gameDataObj = req.body;

                GameData.addGameId(gameDataObj, function (err, doc) {
                    if (err) {
                        if (err.name == "ValidationError") {
                            return res.send("Please send all the required details.");
                        }
                        throw err;
                    };

                    res.json(doc);
              })
        };
    });
});
```

And helper.documentExists

```
module.exports = {
    documentExists: function(collection, query) {
        return collection.count( query ).exec();
    },
};
```

But the script continues to run after this and prints the "required data not found".

```
Output:
    required data not found
    1
```

I am using native ES6 Promises.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

EDIT: Included the entire get route. (will fix those throw err later)

Comment: `console.log("required data not found");` will run whatever the count will be, because it is outside the promise then callback.

Comment: Oh. I assumed that Promise will run before anything that's below it. Was my asumption wrong? And should I add in the rest of the logic under an else block?

Comment: yes you should. see my answer for a bit of insight!!

Comment: If promises made your code wait for them, that would make them pretty useless, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: @Matt: Yeah. That kind of defeats the entire purpose of async code I suppose. So the bext way if branching out the code inside the Promise call right?

Comment: Depends on your dependency. based on that you  can branch code. this helps you take care that only the critical region waits for the promise to be resolved, while others continue undisturbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#######POINT 1#########
ProjectsData.count( {project_id: req.body.project_id} )

    .then(function(c) {
        #######POINT 3#########
        if ( c == 0 ) {
            console.log("1");
            return res.send("The provided Project Id does not exist in our database.");
            console.log("2");
        }
    });
#######POINT 2#########
//some other logic
console.log("required data not found");
```

Following async workflow: after POINT 1, the promise is created and your handler is attached. Now POINT 2 will continue, while (at some future clock the promise is resolved and you reach POINT 3.

With my limited understanding of your workflow/purpose  I'd say simply put POINT 2 code in the `else{}` of the `if` at POINT 3 (as you rightly guessed in the comments). 
EDIT: thanks to @jfriend00 for pointing out a serious mistake in the previous version of my answer.

Comment: @DragoonHP - This answer is wrong.  There's an absolute guarantee that the output from this code will be "required data not found" and then "1" and "2" is never hit because of the `return`.  All `.then()` handlers are guaranteed async on a future clock tick (per the promoise standard) so point 2 is always reached first here between 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right. promises will hit atbest only in the next tick!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code essentially results in this:

```
ProjectsData.count().then(...);
console.log("required data not found");
```

So, of course the second `console.log()` is going to run and print.  Nothing that happens in the `.then()` handler runs until long after the `console.log()` has already run.  And, even then, it can't stop other code from running.   Promises don't make the interpreter "wait".  They just provide structure for you to coordinate your asynchronous operations.

If you want to branch with promises, then you have to branch inside the `.then()` handler, not after it.

---

You don't show enough of the rest of what you're doing to know how to recommend a complete solution.  We need to see the rest of your request in order to help you with the proper branching based on asynchronous results.

---

You probably need something like this:

```
ProjectsData.count( {project_id: req.body.project_id} ).then(function(c) {
    if ( c == 0 ) {
        return res.send("The provided Project Id does not exist in our database.");
    } else {
        // put other logic here
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Added a likely solution, though we really need to see the rest of the related code to know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Can't post the entire code in comment so I'll try to paraphase it > Check if the project exists > If yes, check if data provided is valid > If yes, add a document to mongodb collection.

Comment: @DragoonHP - I was asking you to use "edit" in your question to include the relevant code there.  We can help more completely when you show the whole problem and show real code.

Comment: Okay I edited it in. Sorry for all the confusion. And thank you for all your help. Really apprecaite it. :)

Comment: @DragoonHP - Is your question now solved?  You already accepted the other answer so I won't spend any more time on it if you already have the desired answer.

Comment: Yeah it works as expected, not sure if it's the desired answer or not. I'm a bit new to this and you mentioned that the accepted answer was wrong.

Comment: @DragoonHP - Iceman has has corrected their answer for what I called out as a wrong explanation.  If your code is working and you now understand why, then you're all set.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I understand it. :) Have a great day!